# jQuery File Upload erro parseMetaData

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

Hoje na parte da manhã o jquery File Upload parou de funcionar em todos os locais que eu utilizo, tenho uma base local e outra online, porém as duas apresentam o mesmo erro:
 **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined jquery.fileupload-image.js:262**

tentei fazer o download no site: https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery

porém até a ultima versão que está disponível download apresentando o mesmo problema, alguém saberia o motivo? algum arquivo do jquery atualizou e parou de funcionar sera?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js">    </script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Renan, o arquivo `jquery.fileupload-image` não é da biblioteca `Bootstrap-Image-Gallery`. Tente baixar uma nova versão no site dela: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tags. Caso não resolva, poderia incluir o código de configuração do mesmo?

Comment: Perdão, coloquei o link errado, era para ter colocado o que você me mandou, caso seja possível poderia você baixar e testar? Ate o padrão esta dando este erro, tentei baixar do site e rodar sem fazer nenhuma alteração, porém o problema persiste

Comment: Poderia adicionar a sua pergunta como fez a inclusão e qual ordem dos scripts?

Comment: desculpe wakim, mas não sei como colocar o código no post. eu coloquei porém ele não está aparecendo

Comment: Renan, Edite (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/32570/edit) sua pergunta e adicione o código como normalmente faria para texto comum e idente usando 4 espaços.

Comment: Walkim, já editei

Comment: Renan, notei que alguns scripts estão duplicados, faça uma limpeza. E se puder não use os scripts direto do github, não é uma boa prática. Baixe os recursos para seu servidor/máquina.

Comment: Wakim, resolvi o problema, pelo que parece a versão ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
está com problema apenas mudei para a versão
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
e tudo voltou a funcionar, muito obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda!

Comment: Crie uma resposta com sua solução e aceite-a. Vai ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

O problema estava na versão do jquery.Basta trocar da versão 1.11.0 para 1.11.1

exemplo:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0
```

para:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1
```

Comment: Renan, não esqueça de marcar sua resposta como correta. Da forma que está uma pessoa desatenta não saberia que a pergunta está resolvida.